# Less CSS won't compile in Visual Studio 2013 preview pane if more than 7 imports

Tags: css, visual-studio-2013, less

I'm using VS 2013 and Web Essentials 2.0. A co-worker is using VS 2013 and WE 1.9. We have a less file with 16 imports using:
@import (reference)"folder/LessFileName";

Each of those imports is also importing 16 Less files.

My co-worker is able to compile changes no problem. Once I comment out my imports so there are 7 or less, I can compile fine, but more than 7 VS says it's "compiling 1 dependent file" for a while, then no changes are in the preview. And it doesn't matter which imports get commented out.

I submitted for possible bug in WE 2.0 but wondering if it's something else?

**UPDATE:** After uninstalling the update 2 RC and installing Web Essentials 1.9 I am able to compile with all imports and it's MUCH faster. Seems like a bug to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The author of Web Essentials released a nightly build that solved my problem.